# How to find g-forces for 3 axis accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, magnitude

I am working on collecting 3 axis accelerometer data from an input file. I have extracted the x, y, z values but don;t know how to get the g forces for the accelerometer with 0g being half-scale and the range of the accelerometer is +/-5g. 
Any formulas to use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends if it is linear or not. (Data sheet should inform about that with nice diagrams). If it is linear it is simple school math. Of course, if the sensor was giving analog output, you also will have to consider your AD converter circuitry. Lets assume it was a analog sensor with -500...500 mV output range and your AD converter was some 16 bit AD... and that it has a matching input range. Then you end up with 32768 = 0mv = 0g, 0 = -500mV = -5g and so on.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand this. lets say I have x, y, z values as 8, 13, 15 for a linear acclerometer, how would you get the half scale and +/-5g into consideration for this to calculate g forces? arent the g-forces then used to calculate magnitude = sqrt(xg^2 + yg^2 + zg^2)?

Comment: Yes you can see it as a vector and then compute the magnitude. But usually, people want the vector for subsequent computation steps.

Comment: I'll try that! thanks so much